# Regular expression for checking

Tags: python, regex

I am facing a problem with regular expression in Python.
The problem is that "Have to check a list and have to find out space containing strings."
The code is:

```
def testFunction(self, func): 
        a = re.findall(r'\w+[\ ]*\(.*?\)', func)
        j = len(a)
        print j
        if j<=1:
            return True

        else:
           s = re.findall(r"function *()", func) # cheking 
            t = len(s) # calculating the lenth
            if t<=0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

It returns all time true whether there is a gap or nor.
Example:it detects both "test()" & "test ()"
With in a word i am searching for a regular expression it will search for the gap inside a string.It will detect only "test ()" not "test()"
I tried with **regex = r'\w+[\ ]*(.*?)' 
              regex = r'^\s*'**
but unfortunately does not work.
The work can be done by a regular expression that will differ between test(arg1) & 
test (arg1).
Thanks.

Comment: If "space" and not "white space", why not `l = ["a b", "c", "d e"]; [x for a in l if a.find(" ") != -1]` ?

Answer (score 2):

if all you care about is whether there are **any** spaces, why not just do something like

```
return " " in func
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this `r'.*\s+.*'`

Answer (score 2):

[\ ]* matches zero or more occurrences of space. Try [\ ]+ instead

Comment: What the heck is `[\ ]` supposed to be? Couldn’t you obfuscate that any further??? ☹

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r"function\ *\(\)", func)
```

Answer (score 0):

HI,
I have done this by

```
 def testFunction(self, func): 
       #this function looks for a "function",looks for "function"  both with and without parameter & with parameter
        a = re.findall(r'\s', func)
        j = len(a)
        if j<=1:
            return True
        else:
                return False
```

Thanks a lot :)